# Pythonのwhile文でエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Pythonでセルの値が2のセルをWhile文を使って一行一行下に進みながら探すコードを書きたいと思っていますが、現状では以下のコードを実行すると＜エラー＞が表示されてしまいます。
構文の間違いを教えていただけませんでしょうか？どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop")
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet=wb["Task"]

i=1
sheet.cell(row=i,column=1)
Need2=sheet.cell(row=i,column=1)

while True:
    Need2.value(2)
    Need2.row += 1
    print(Need2)
```

**＜エラー＞**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-087799fac3f5> in <module>
     10 
     11 while True:
---> 12     Need2.value(2)
     13     Need2.row += 1
     14     print(Need2)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この仕様 [openpyxl.cell.cell module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html) を元に推測すると、以下のように考えられます。

- cellの`value`を2と比較するのに`value(2)`という使い方は存在しないでしょう。
  `if Need2.value == 2:` で比較するのでは？

続けて、次の行もおかしいでしょう。

- `row`プロパティは読み込みだけの可能性があります。
  この流れで次の`row`のcellが欲しいなら、`Need2 = Need2.offset(row=1,column=0)`でしょうか。
  一応 `+= 1` が出来そうなコメントもありましたが、推奨しないようです。
  [find cell value with matching regular expression of a row in excel file](https://python-forum.io/Thread-find-cell-value-with-matching-regular-expression-of-a-row-in-excel-file)
- 2を検出した次の`row`に移ってから`print()`するという処理のようですが本当ですか？
- ループを抜ける処理がありません。
  処理が終了しないか、データが無い`row`で例外終了するのでは？
- 上記終了条件にも関連しますが、`value`が2のcellが見つかったら何をどうしますか？
  あるいはそれが複数存在する場合は？

こんな記事があって、参考になると思います。
[Using openpyxl to search for a cell in one column and then to print out the row for that relevant cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38732979/9014308)

> If you only want to look in column A for the input I would do something like this:
>
> ```
> for i in range(1,ws.max_row):
>     if ws.cell(row=row, column=0).value == date:
>         for j in range(i, ws.max_column):
>             print (ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
> ```
>
> Assuming you want to print every column on the row matching the input

注）上記参考記事回答で先頭の日付値が合う行を全てprintしているように見えましたが、いろいろと間違っていそうです。
先頭`column`に0を指定している、変数`j`の`range()`を`i`から始めている、`range()`で最後の行・列が入らない指定になっている、`print()` に指定したcellに値が入っているか考慮していない、あたり（結局全部？）がダメでしょうか。

ループの形の考え方だけ参考ですかね。